# What, if anything, is the sum of all complex numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, complex-numbers, summation, definition

*If this question is ill-defined or is otherwise of poor quality, then I'm sorry.*

> What, *if anything*, is the sum of all complex numbers?

If anything at all, it's an uncountable sum, that's for sure.

I'm guessing some version of the [Riemann series theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) would mean that there is no such thing as ***the*** sum of complex numbers, although - and I hesitate to add this - I would imagine that

$$\sum_{z\in\Bbb C}z=0\tag{$\Sigma$}$$

is, in some sense, what one might call the "principal value" of the sum. For all $w\in\Bbb C$, we have $-w\in\Bbb C$ with $w+(-w)=0$, so, if we proceed naïvely, we could say that we are summing $0$ infinitely many times${}^\dagger$, hence $(\Sigma)$.

We have to make clear what we mean by "sum", though, since, of course, with real numbers, one can define all sorts of different types of infinite sums. I'm at a loss here.

Has this sort of thing been studied before?

I'd be surprised if not.

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$ I'm well aware that this is a bit *too* naïve. It's not something I take seriously.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Traditionally, the sum of a sequence is defined as the limit of the partial sums; that is, for a sequence $\{a_n\}$, $\sum{a_n}$ is that number $S$ so that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N$ such that whenever $m > N$, $|S - \sum_{n = 0}^ma_n| < \epsilon$. There's no reason we can't define it like that for uncountable sequences as well: let $\mathfrak{c}$ be the cardinality of $\mathbb{C}$, and let $\{a_{\alpha}\}$ be a sequence of complex numbers where the indices are ordinals less than $\mathfrak{c}$. We define $\sum{a_{\alpha}}$ as that value $S$ so that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\beta < \mathfrak{c}$ so that whenever $\gamma > \beta$, $|S - \sum_{\alpha = 0}^{\gamma}a_{\alpha}| < \epsilon$. Note that this requires us to recursively define transfinite summation, to make sense of that sum up to $\gamma$.

But here's the thing: taking $\epsilon$ to be $1$, then $1/2$, then $1/4$, and so on, we get a sequence of "threshold" $\beta$ corresponding to each one; call $\beta_n$ the $\beta$ corresponding to $\epsilon = 1/2^n$. This is a countable sequence (length strictly less than $\mathfrak{c}$). Inconveniently, $\mathfrak{c}$ is *regular*: any increasing sequence of ordinals less than $\mathfrak{c}$ with length less than $\mathfrak{c}$ must be bounded *strictly* below $\mathfrak{c}$. So that means there's some $\beta_{\infty}$ that's below $\mathfrak{c}$ but greater than every $\beta_n$. But by definition, that means that all partial sums past $\beta_{\infty}$ are less than $1/2^n$ away from $S$ *for every $n$*. So they must be exactly equal to $S$. And that means that we must be only adding $0$ from that point forward.

This is a well-known result that I can't recall a reference for: the only uncountable sequences that have convergent sums are those which consist of countably many nonzero terms followed by nothing but zeroes. In other words, there's no sensible way to sum over all of the complex numbers and get a convergence.

Comment: How does one mentally reconcile this information with the idea of an integral? You could view that as a continuous sum.

Comment: That's a very good question, @orlp; I think I'll withdraw the acceptance of this answer until I understand what it implies about integrals.

Comment: The regularity of $\mathfrak{c}$ is really a red herring here (and in fact, $\mathfrak{c}$ may not be regular!).  You could just as well pick an enumeration of $\mathbb{C}$ whose length has countable cofinality, and then there might not be any point beyond which all the terms are $0$.  What you can prove though (independent of the ordering used) is that only countably many terms can be nonzero.  (Proof: if there are uncountably many nonzero terms, apply your argument to the first partial sum which contains uncountably many nonzero terms, which must have cofinality $\omega_1$.)

Comment: As for the regularity of $\mathfrak{c}$, it is consistent with ZFC that $\mathfrak{c}$ is singular (for instance, it could be $\aleph_{\omega_1}$).  However, it follows from König's theorem that it has uncountable cofiinality so your argument still does work for it.

Comment: @orlp An integral isn't an infinite sum; it's an infinite *average*. You're effectively dividing each term by a measure of the "number" of terms, rendering it infinitesimal; in this case, the uncountable analogue of infinitesimal. That means it doesn't really resemble a "sum" in the sense we usually mean (for example, the integral of the function $f(x)$ which is $1$ at $0$ and $1$ and zero elsewhere is not $2$).

Comment: @EricWofsey: I would upvote an answer which contains the details of your comments here. It seems to me that this line of thought addresses the core issue, namely why some kind of "finiteness" and/or "countability" *must be* enforced in convergent sums (rather than building the finiteness/countability into the definition, as the other answers do).

Comment: @LeeMosher: I don't agree; sums are _obviously_ inherently finite, since addition is defined as a finitary operation.  When we try to define "convergent sums", we are just taking a limit of finite sums one way or another.  The only difference is what "shape" of limits we take--iterated limits over a well-ordered set in Reese's answer, or limits of finite partial sums over a net in Keenan Kidwell's answer.  And this only ever makes a difference if you are talking about "conditional convergence" rather than "absolute convergence".

Comment: In particular, I would strenuously object to your implication that Keenan Kidwell's answer "builds finiteness into the definition" in a way that makes the necessity of having only countably many terms a sort of tautology.  That's completely wrong--the necessity of having only countably many terms comes not from the finiteness of the partial sums but from the first-countability of the topology in which we are taking the limits.  In topological abelian groups that are not first-countable, you can have truly uncountable convergent sums in that sense.

Comment: Thanks, good points. Your last point regarding non first countable examples is something I was wondering about. But that makes for a different question.

Comment: I will stand by one of my points though. This (Reese's) answer, with your comments taken into account, shows that it is not necessary to mention finiteness/countability properties in the *definition* of an infinite sum. Instead, those properties are *derived* (by making use of the first-countability property that follows from the definition of a metric space itself, as you have pointed out).

Comment: $\Bbb C$ is a set, not a sequence. So before one could apply this definition, one would have to impose some indexing, and it would be reasonable to suspect that the answer (if it exists) might depend on what indexing one uses.

Comment: @Acccumulation That's correct, but please note that my argument above applies to *any* indexing. Which means that any indexing of $\mathbb{C}$ (which has uncountably many nonzero elements) must have divergent sum.

Comment: I think that the transfinite argument is overkill: the fact that non-zeros are countable follows easily from the fact that given any $\epsilon >0$, the number of numbers with magnitude greater than $\epsilon$ must be finite, and we have a countable sequence of $\epsilon$s going to zero.

Answer (score 15):

If $\{z_i:i\in I\}$ is any indexed set of complex numbers, then the series $\sum_{i\in I}z_i$ is said to converge to the complex number $z$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite subset $J_\epsilon$ of $I$ such that, for every finite subset $J$ of $I$ with $J_\epsilon\subseteq J$, $\vert \sum_{i\in J}z_i-z\vert<\epsilon$. In other words, to say that the series converges to $z$ is to say that the net $J\mapsto\sum_{i\in J}z_i$, from finite subsets of $I$ directed by inclusion, converges to $z$. This is a special case of the standard definition of unordered summation which works in an arbitrary commutative (Hausdorff) topological group. A comprehensive reference for this kind of summation is section 5 of Chapter III of Bourbaki's *General Topology*. In particular, because $\mathbf{C}$ is first-countable, the corollary on page 263 of *loc. cit.* implies that, if such a $z$ exists, then the set $\{i\in I:z_i\neq 0\}$ is countable (such a result was mentioned in the answer by Reese, but it is not necessary to use any kind of transfinite recursion to make sense of this kind of summation).

So, unless you want to introduce a nonstandard notion of summation (which necessarily must lack some of the features one would hope for based on the case of finite sums), the series in question cannot be meaningfully said to converge to anything.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that no such sum can be defined uniquely. If one limits to summation methods that are symmetric around the origin, the conditional limit could be zero. (The process would be to sum over squares (-x,-ix; x, -ix; x, ix, -x, ix) such that each set of 4 points sums to zero (as does the origin.) Of course,summing over (-x,-ix; 2x, -ix; 2x, ix, -x, ix) would give a result that becomes arbitrarily large.  By playing around with summation methods one could generate any result.